# In rspec what does a test that ends with 'to be' mean?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-expectations

You can find an example at 
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cloud_controller_ng/blob/c63d33c0b1c2298d49a0bad959222b9c3daba16a/spec/unit/controllers/services/service_instances_controller_spec.rb#L1748 :

The second test in this block shows this:

```
expect(last_response).to have_status_code 202
expect(decoded_response['entity']['guid']).to be
expect(decoded_response['entity']['status']).to eq 'queued'
```

I see that we're matching against a new instance of `Matchers::BuiltIn::Be`,
but at this point it's hard to see what we're actually matching against.

Ruby 2.1.3, rspec 3.0.0, rspec-expectations 3.0.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [`be` matchers](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/be-matchers) documentation, `expect(obj).to be` this test passes if `obj` is *truthy* (not `nil` or `false`).

`expect(decoded_response['entity']['guid']).to be` means as documentation said, if the value of `decoded_response['entity']['guid']` is any object, but not `nil` or `false`, the test will pass.

Here is a *demo* example :

```
RSpec.describe "be matcher" do
  context "when object is truthy" do
    specify { expect(2).to be }
  end
  context "when object is not truthy" do
    specify { expect(nil).not_to be }
  end
end
```

Lets run this test :-

```
[arup@Ruby]$ rspec --format d spec/a_spec.rb

be matcher
  when object is truthy
    should be
  when object is not truthy
    should not be

Finished in 0.00254 seconds (files took 0.42175 seconds to load)
2 examples, 0 failures
```